# How to remove grid background on SVG image using Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, svg, background-removal

I'm using the Meteocons icon set in my project, specifically the SVG files. I noticed they all display on screen with a light blue 'grid' as a background.

How can I remove this background so that the image is fully transparent? I'm using Inkscape. I'd like to keep the canvas/document size the same.

[image]

Please bear with me as I am new to graphic design. Thanks in advance.

Ref: http://www.alessioatzeni.com/meteocons/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I opened a few of the SVGs in Inkscape, the grid is just an object. In Inkscape, just single click the grid and press the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key.

You can single click and drag the grid, just to make certain that you selected it and not part of the icon.